# Android Studio start activity when detected an bluetooth device by MAC Address/UUID?

Tags: android-studio, bluetooth, android-studio-2.2

I am making application that will run specific activity when **detected** an bluetooth iBeacon (not when connected because iBeacon is just transmiting signal)

I have multiple iBeacons each one will start different activity so the application need to recognize each beacons by MAC Address/UUID

My Application are now able to scan iBeacon device

but to make them start activity and recognize each one. I don't know how to start

---

I used the code from here (not my project)

https://github.com/danasf/hm10-android-arduino/tree/master/Android/BT4LEDTest

I didn't change his code much so it should be similar to my current code (if I post all my code it's exceed 30000 char limit)

Answer (score 1):

for specific device, you will get list of available device nearby apart from it you will get information like  mac as each device as unique mac id

You can start activity from service once you get onConnectionStateChange callback where Bluetooth device is connected.

or 
you can broadcast event for successful connection event and 'onreceive()'  start activity.

Comment: Thanks! Can this method detect specific bluetooth device by MAC Address/UUID?

Comment: BluetoothDevice https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html